# AsyncListUtil keeps old data after refresh

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I use AsyncListUtil to load the items from the database in the background.

If the tile size is 50, the AsyncListUtil doesn't clear the cache after `refresh()`.Recycle view shows the top 6 items in the old list, but it should show the last 6 items. It's okay when the tile size is 5.

Is there any limit of tile size? Or there is something wrong in my code?

Here is the sample code which also has the same problem.

```
public class AsyncListUtilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "AsyncListUtilActivity";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        textList.addAll(Arrays.asList(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new AsyncAdapter(textList));
        setContentView(mRecyclerView);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menu.add("Layout"), MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for(int i = textList.size() - 1; i >= textList.size() - 6 ; --i) {
            tmpList.add(textList.get(i));
        }
        textList.clear();
        textList.addAll(tmpList);
        ((AsyncAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).refresh();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public TextViewHolder(Context context) {
            super(new TextView(context));
            textView = (TextView) itemView;
        }
    }
    private class AsyncAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextViewHolder> {
        private AsyncListUtil<String> mAsyncListUtil;
        AsyncAdapter(final List<String> textList) {
            mAsyncListUtil = new AsyncStringListUtil(textList);
        }
        @Override
        public TextViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new TextViewHolder(parent.getContext());
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(TextViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final String itemString = mAsyncListUtil.getItem(position);
            if (itemString == null) {
                holder.textView.setText("loading...");
            } else {
                holder.textView.setText(itemString);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mAsyncListUtil.getItemCount();
        }

        public void refresh() {
            mAsyncListUtil.refresh();
        }
    }
    private class AsyncStringListUtil extends AsyncListUtil<String> {
        private static final int TILE_SIZE = 50;
        private static final long DELAY_MS = 500;
        public AsyncStringListUtil(final List<String> textList) {
            super(String.class, TILE_SIZE,
                    new AsyncListUtil.DataCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int refreshData() {
                            return textList.size();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void fillData(String[] data, int startPosition, int itemCount) {
                            sleep();
                            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                                data[i] = textList.get(startPosition + i);
                            }
                        }
                        private void sleep() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new AsyncListUtil.ViewCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void getItemRangeInto(int[] outRange) {
                            outRange[0] = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                            outRange[1] = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onDataRefresh() {
                            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onItemLoaded(int position) {
                            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);
                        }
                    });
            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    onRangeChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ItemSource. Just call `itemSource.update();` before          `listUtil.refresh();`